# Gitlab: remove notebooks from language percentage

Tags: python, gitlab, jupyter

At the top of a Gitlab project, there is a bar showing the percentage of each language used inside the project.

In my repository I have dozens of large python files and one little notebook with a few lines of code, but it shows that the project contains mostly notebooks. This is not a bug, it's just related to the fact that plots in particular generates tons of raw lines in the `.ipynb` files.

I want to avoid this behavior, e.g. by telling Gitlab not to count the lines of this file. I found some solutions for Github, but not for Gitlab.

NB: I don't want to create an extra repository to host one little notebook, even though it would solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add to (or create) your `.gitattributes` file with the following content:

```
*.ipynb -linguist-detectable
```

This will tell linguist to ignore these files when calculating the languages. Similar attributes should also work, like `linguist-vendored` or `linguist-generated`.

Also note, per [the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/#repository-languages) changes to the `.gitattributes` file must be committed to the root of the **default branch** of the project to take effect.

Comment: Thanks, I was desperately looking for this!